# How to set Ordering in unity C# so that higher y value always takes priority

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d unity game where it is crucial that the sprite with a lower y value always renders in front of sprites with higher y values(in the game sprites would move so I couldn't just set it via inspector).

I tried constantly checking this through Update function but it reduced performance significantly and didn't work halve the time.

Comment: Add the code here, maybe some screenshots, anything, which increases the chance for others to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.